# Limit for Dynamic query in oracle

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, limit

I need some help in finding a solution for dynamic query if there is a limit of characters.

I have 7 variables, each defined of varchar2(4000).

i have checked the length of each variable and all together they total to 4217.

And i try to execute the dynamic query using the below syntax.

```
OPEN p_Cursor FOR v_Query || v_I || vW1 || v_W2 || v_O || v_ODir || v_Join
USING value1, value2, value3;
```

I get errors, and thought to display the query and it fails to display.
when i remove the last 2 variables, it displays the query.

**ERROR:
Execution failed: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01003: no statement parsed**

Is there a limit that dynamic query accepts?

I figured the issue..........

Comment: What are the contents of the variables? (Roughly, as posting a 4000 character query is ill-advised.)

Comment: they have query, select, columns, joins where all those

Comment: It's kind of worrisome that you have a query consisting of over 4200 characters. I've had some pretty hefty queries, but I doubt I've ever broken a couple hundred characters. Not to mention the fact you're using dynamic SQL. Maybe there's a way to simplify it? Maybe this should actually be multiple, independent queries?

Comment: all together they make 4200 characters.
the scenario is it has select columns, inner select query, joins and  filters....thts all it contains..there is nothing more to minimise

Comment: Yes, but all together, they're a single query to be passed into a `CURSOR`. Sounds highly, highly error prone. This could be anything.

Comment: why would it be a highly, highly error prone?
I have implemented several procs with same usage, its just that it has lot of queries

Comment: Because the bigger, longer, and more complicated something is, the easier it is to make some little mistake somewhere, and in Oracle, some little mistake somewhere can screw everything up without giving you any clue why or even where. =/ You can't focus on the details as much. There's a reason people cite the KISS philosophy. Keep your code in short and simple pieces as much as possible, and you'll get it right far more often.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion....any idea on how to overcome this scenario??

Comment: Hard to know what happens without seeing the query, but `ORA-01003` happens when you `try to open a cursor with no associated parsed SQL statement`. Make sure that at least one of those variables contains SQL. If at least one does, get the complete `SQL` sentence just before opening the cursor and try to execute it via SQL*Plus, Toad or whatever you are using to work on Oracle.

Comment: You might consider encapsulating as much as possible of the query logic into views, as that would greatly reduce the size of the query you're constructing and make it easier to see if there's an error in the query construction.

Comment: Which Orale version do you have? In 10g the limit was 4k

Answer (score 1):

I have found it useful to place the command into a variable and output it before I execute it. This allows you to review what you are actually executing:

```
DECLARE
   l_cmd   VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
   l_cmd   := v_query || v_i || vw1 || v_w2 || v_o || v_odir || v_join;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_cmd);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL has always supported strings of 32767 characters, [including in dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/whatsnew.htm#CHDGIGFJ).  In 11g that was raised to CLOB.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/openfor_statement.htm#LNPLS01333).  So it seems unlikely that the simple length of your statement is to blame, provided your calculation of the total length of the statement is correct.

You say "to display the query and it fails to display"  but you don't say how and what error you get.  Let's assume DBMS_OUTPUT.  Dropping off the last two variables allows the statement to be displayed, so it seems likely the size of the statement is a problem. Again, the buffer for PUT_LINE() is 32767.  Even if the problem is a buffer overflow, because you're not specifying `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE << big number>>` the default is 20000, which is way bigger than 4217.  So my previous caveat about the length of the statement applies here.

---

Anyway, the ORA-01003 means that the dynamic statement wasn't parsed, it has a bug (or bugs).  A common error when assembling dynamic queries like this is to forget the spaces between key words.

Consider this:

```
v1 := 'select * from';
t := 'EMP'

open refc for v1||t;
```

The problem is, the concatenated statement is  `select * fromEMP`.  Not valid SQL.